# Oracle SQL - Query for Changes to Database

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently experiencing an issue. We are trying to build a report where we can see the changes between a field from one moment in time to another. For instance, a small example would be that we want the report to produce their last name 6 months ago and their last name as of today.

Is there a SQL expression that can do this for me? (e.g. add a SQL date parameter to the first last name column where the data is from 6 months ago).

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output to clarify

Comment: Does your "database" (whatever that means) store historical information, or only current information? That is - say you have a table with "employees" and one column is "last_name" - do you have an "effective_date" column in this table, and you only `INSERT` into the table instead of `UPDATE`ing it? That's the standard way to store information if you may need historical information in your reports.

Comment: I marked your question as "too broad" because answer will be based on how you store historical data. since you didn't provide enough info, no one can answer it

Answer (score 1):

Use a [flashback query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008) (you will have to ensure the database is set up to support this first and has enough flashback retention to handle 6 months of data):

```
SELECT COALESCE( current.id, previous.id ) AS id,
       current.name  AS current_name,
       previous.name AS name_six_months_ago
FROM   table_name current
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT id, name
         FROM   table_name
         AS OF TIMESTAMP ( ADD_MONTHS( SYSTIMESTAMP, -6 ) )
       ) previous
       ON ( current.id = previous.id );
```